# mysql Dynamic search query indexing

Tags: mysql, performance, indexing

It's my first project, so I'm sorry I have so many questions.

I'm trying to index to search the above Cat table.

However, I don't know how to apply it because the where clause has multiple cases.

```
SELECT *
FROM CAT
WHERE birth between '2000-01-01' and '2009-12-31';

SELECT *
FROM CAT
WHERE birth between '2000-01-01' and '2009-12-31'
and NAME like '%blue%';

SELECT *
FROM CAT
WHERE NAME like '%blue%'
AND AGE = 5;
```

If so, can I create indexes on age, name, and birth respectively?
If not, do I have to create (age), (age,name), (age,birth), (age,name,birth).... for every case?

Even after reading the book, I am not sure, so I leave a question. I hope you don't feel bad about it.

i use mysql v8.0 innoDB.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
WHERE birth between '2000-01-01' and '2009-12-31'
```

*may* be helped by

```
INDEX(birth)
```

However note:  If `birth` is of type `DATETIME`, you have left out most of 12/31.

```
and NAME like '%blue%';
```

Because of the *leading* wildcard, no index will help.

```
AND AGE = 5
```

is bad schema design.  Think what happens when the cat has a birthday.  You have to update that column.  Instead do some date arithmetic with `birth` and `CURDATE()`.

But if you do keep an `age` column, then this *may* help:

```
INDEX(age)
```

I covered `cat.birth` queries in another Question today; see it.  And see my [*Index Cookbook*](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/index_cookbook_mysql) for more discussion of how to build a suitable index for a given `SELECT`.  It shows what cases of `WHERE ... AND ...` can use a "composite" (multi-column) `INDEX` to good advantage.  None of your examples can make use of a composite index.

Comment: Thank you. I'm late in choosing an answer because I didn't understand well. sorry.